# python re search for exactly one repeat of a specific character

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with python 're' and I'm looking for a pattern that matches `[some text]` but skip `[[another text]]`. For example if the input is like this:

```
'[aaa]bb[[cd]]'
```

then output be like this:

```
bb[[cd]]
```

I already tried `r'(\[){1}(.*?)(\]){1}'` and `r'\[[^\[](.*?)[^\]]\]'` and none of them worked properly.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things:

- to ensure there are no other square brackets between your square brackets: that can easily be done using a character class without square brackets `[^\]\[]`
- to ensure there isn't an other opening square bracket before the opening square bracket and there isn't a closing square bracket after the closing square bracket *(note that this second test can be optional if you think that the first suffices)*. To do that you can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` *(a zero-width assertion that checks backward if a subpattern fails from the current position)* and a negative lookahead `(?!...)` *(a zero-width assertion that checks forward if a subpattern fails from the current position)*.

Result:

```
r'(?<!\[)\[([^\]\[]*)\](?!\])'
```

Note that *zero-width assertion* means that the characters described in the subpatterns aren't consumed. In other words, the characters before the `[`
and after the `]` aren't replaced if you use this pattern with `re.sub`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Positive Lookbehind (?<=(\[aaa\]))`

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=(\[aaa\])).+'
text='[aaa]bb[[cd]]'

match=re.search(pattern,text)
print(match.group())
```

output:

```
bb[[cd]]
```

Explanation:

```
\[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)

aaa matches the characters aaa literally (case sensitive)

\] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group (\[aaa\])

(?<=foo)    Lookbehind  Asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is foo
```

P.S : If there are many matches in same line then use finditer instead of re.search

Comment: Using a lookarounds is a good idea, but what you suggest doesn't answer the question. *(see the two patterns in the question)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i saw the pattern and i saw the expected output too. I gave the output basis on data which she provided. And if you have better solution than mine , Please suggest i just shown a way i didn't said that you *must* use this method.